# Can somebody please rollback this answer posing as an edit?

Tags: support

Not sure why I can't roll this back (not sure if its priveledge or because OP edited after)

https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32211135/5

Edit starts with:

> What you want is this:

Comment: you should really be flagging that for a mod to look at regardless, so that they can make sure that the person that approved the edit gets a time out from reviewing.

Comment: flagged, thanks, I flagged the question though, couldn't figure out how to flag the edit

Comment: You flag the question and then link to (and/or just describe) the specific revision in your message to the mod.

Answer (score 4):

I've rolled back the edit.  Not sure why you couldn't, as all you need is the 2k rep to edit posts to roll back edits.

Comment: I think maybe because I hit my review limit for the day

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum That would only be relevant if the edit hadn't been approved yet, and was still pending.  Once it was approved you'd have been able to roll it back.

Comment: @Glenn Teitelbaum: I notice the suggested edit was supplemented by a review edit, creating two distinct revisions that each have their own rollback links. That could have been the problem - clicking rollback on the suggested edit will fail silently. Not sure if it's been reported yet, as ideally it should be hidden if it's expected that the two revisions be tied together. You'd need to click rollback on the revision *before* the suggested one to revert to that particular revision.